# How to pass a file handle to a subroutine/function?

Tags: c++, function, file, pointers

I have several files I am accessing on an SD card.
My code all works, but almost half my code is repeated
functions/subroutines. I have tried using pointers to pass
the file name/handle to the function so I don't have to repeat
the functions (doing the same thing) for each
file. I'm still learning C, and am weak with pointers, I'm
guessing that's the way to do it. Help appreciated.

```c
File SDconFile;                          //SD File2 to keep connect info
String FName2 = "Connect1.txt";          //USER: SD card file keep connect info

char openFile2(byte RW, String FN) {     //Open SD FName2 file. char RW. Only 1 at a time.
  SDconFile.close();                     //Ensure file status, before re-opening
  SDconFile = SD.open(FN, RW);}          //Open Read at end.  Open at EOF for write/append
```

It's the SDconFile part I want to pass.

Comment: Are you using standard C functions like `fopen()` to open the files?  If so, the correct type to use is `FILE *` (case matters in C).  If not, then the `File` type is not standard C and you need to identify how the functions you use work.  The manual should describe what to do.

Comment: It is Arduino C++.

Comment: C++, you have tagged the question as C. Please edit and replace C tag with C++.

Comment: I don't know about Arduino, but in regular C++, I'd either use `File *` (pointer) or `File &` (reference).